# Trying to make an HP bar for a game using HTML/JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make a health bar for a game where I have 2 buttons linked to the bar, one adds damage and the other adds health. I have it all designed the way I want it but am having trouble with the JavaScript part. The buttons are linked but when I click to add damage or health it only adjusts the amount of HP by one in either direction but no more than that. I also can't figure out how to make the width of the bar move with the number associated with the amount of health. I think I'm close but just need a little help. I'll add the CSS code too so there is some more context.

```js
function add() {
  let addHealth = document.getElementById('health')
  let width = 100;
  addHealth.width += 1;

  if (addHealth) {
    addHealth.style.width = width + '%';
    addHealth.innerHTML = width * 1 + 'hp';
  }
}

function remove() {
  let damage = document.getElementById('health')
  let width = 100;
  damage.width -= 1;

  if (damage) {
    damage.style.width = width + '%';
    damage.innerHTML = width - 1 + 'hp';
  }
}
```

```css
.hp {
  text-align: center;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
}

.gage {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 500px;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
}

.bar {
  height: 60px;
  position: relative;
  background: #555;
  -moz-border-radius: 25px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 25px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  padding: 10px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 -1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
}

.bar>span {
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  border-top-right-radius: 8px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 8px;
  border-top-left-radius: 20px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
  background-color: rgb(43, 194, 83);
  background-image: linear-gradient( center bottom, rgb(43, 194, 83) 37%, rgb(84, 240, 84) 69%);
  box-shadow: inset 0 2px 9px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3), inset 0 -2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.lvl {
  background-color: #078a25;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #078a25, #f36d0a);
}

#health {
  font-size: 20px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: right;
}

.btn-3d {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 22px;
  padding: 20px 60px;
  color: white;
  margin: 20px 10px 10px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  text-align: center;
  transition: top .01s linear;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  cursor: pointer;
}

.btn-3d.green:hover {
  background-color: #80C49D;
}

.btn-3d:active {
  top: 9px;
}

.btn-3d.green {
  background-color: #82c8a0;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #82c8a0 inset, 0 0 0 2px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) inset, 0 8px 0 0 rgba(126, 194, 155, .7), 0 8px 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .4), 0 8px 8px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.btn-3d.green:active {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #82c8a0 inset, 0 0 0 2px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) inset, 0 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}

.btn-3d.red:hover {
  background-color: #e74c3c;
}

.btn-3d.red {
  background-color: #e74c3c;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #c63702 inset, 0 0 0 2px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) inset, 0 8px 0 0 #C24032, 0 8px 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4), 0 8px 8px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.btn-3d.red:active {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #c63702 inset, 0 0 0 2px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) inset, 0 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
```

```html
<div class="hp">
  <div class="gage">
    <div class="bar">
      <span id="health" class="lvl" style="width: 100%">100hp</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="click">
    <span class="btn-3d green" onclick="add()">Health</span>
    <span class="btn-3d red" onclick="remove()">Damage</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Also, if anyone has any ideas to improve the design I'm all ears!

Comment: That is some weird code. Basically you never change the value `width`. You merely change `addHealth.width`.

Comment: The HP bar should be done with SVG, not with HTML.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

it's better to use the object to control the limitation.

```
  const healthObject = {
      _currentHelth: 100,
      getHealth: function () {
        return this._currentHelth
      },
      increase: function () {
        if (this._currentHelth < 100) {
          this._currentHelth++
        }
      },
      decrease: function () {
        if (this._currentHelth > 0) {
          this._currentHelth--
        }
      },
    }

    function add() {
      let addHealth = document.getElementById('health')
      healthObject.increase()
      if (addHealth) {
        addHealth.style.width = healthObject.getHealth() + '%'
        addHealth.innerHTML = healthObject.getHealth() + 'hp'
      }
    }

function remove() {
  let addHealth = document.getElementById('health')
  healthObject.decrease()
  if (addHealth) {
    addHealth.style.width = healthObject.getHealth() + '%'
    addHealth.innerHTML = healthObject.getHealth() + 'hp'
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This makes a lot of sense. It also gave me some ideas to play around with the functionality a little more.

Answer (score 0):

In your example you merely change the output but never the actual health `width` itself. Here is a quick analysis

```
function add() {
    //REM: You fetch the element correctly;
    let addHealth = document.getElementById('health')
    //REM: You reset the heath to 100 for some reason?
    let width = 100;
    //REM: You change a width property of the element?
    //REM: Here you should reduce the value of width
    addHealth.width += 1;

    if (addHealth) {
        //REM: You set the width of the element according to the health, which seems correct
        addHealth.style.width = width + '%'; 
        //REM: You set the displayed value to 100, since width always gets set to 100 inside the function
        addHealth.innerHTML = width * 1  + 'hp';
    }
}
```

The most simple way is to store the health in a seperate variable and build on that.

```js
var _Health = 100; //REM: Default HP

function add() {
 let addHealth = document.getElementById('health')
 _Health += 1;

 if (addHealth) {
  addHealth.style.width = _Health + '%'; 
     addHealth.innerHTML = _Health + 'hp';
    }
}

function remove() {
 let damage = document.getElementById('health')
 _Health -= 1;

 if(damage) {
  damage.style.width = _Health + '%'; 
      damage.innerHTML = _Health + 'hp';
 }
}
```

```css
.hp {
 text-align: center;
 padding-bottom: 50px;
}

.gage {
 display: inline-block;
 width: 500px;
 padding-bottom: 30px;
}

.bar { 
 height: 60px;
 position: relative;
 background: #555;
 -moz-border-radius: 25px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 25px;
 border-radius: 25px;
 padding: 10px;
 box-shadow: inset 0 -1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
}

.bar > span {
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  border-top-right-radius: 8px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 8px;
  border-top-left-radius: 20px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
  background-color: rgb(43,194,83);
  background-image: linear-gradient(
    center bottom,
    rgb(43,194,83) 37%,
    rgb(84,240,84) 69%
  );
  box-shadow: 
    inset 0 2px 9px  rgba(255,255,255,0.3),
    inset 0 -2px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.lvl {
  background-color: #078a25;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #078a25, #f36d0a);
}

#health {
 font-size: 20px;
 color: white;
 font-weight: bold;
 text-align: right;
}

.btn-3d {
 position: relative;
 display: inline-block;
 font-size: 22px;
 padding: 20px 60px;
 color: white;
 margin: 20px 10px 10px;
 border-radius: 6px;
 text-align: center;
 transition: top .01s linear;
 text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
 cursor: pointer;
}

.btn-3d.green:hover  {background-color: #80C49D;}

.btn-3d:active {
 top: 9px;
}

.btn-3d.green {
 background-color: #82c8a0;
 box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #82c8a0 inset,
    0 0 0 2px rgba(255,255,255,0.15) inset,
    0 8px 0 0 rgba(126, 194, 155, .7),
    0 8px 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,.4),
    0 8px 8px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
.btn-3d.green:active {
 box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #82c8a0 inset,
    0 0 0 2px rgba(255,255,255,0.15) inset,
    0 0 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
}

.btn-3d.red:hover    {background-color: #e74c3c;}

.btn-3d.red {
 background-color: #e74c3c;
 box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #c63702 inset,
        0 0 0 2px rgba(255,255,255,0.15) inset,
        0 8px 0 0 #C24032,
        0 8px 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.4),
    0 8px 8px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
.btn-3d.red:active {
 box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #c63702 inset,
    0 0 0 2px rgba(255,255,255,0.15) inset,
    0 0 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
}
```

```html
<div class="hp">
  <div class="gage">
   <div class="bar">
    <span id="health" class="lvl" style="width: 100%">100hp</span>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="click">
   <span class="btn-3d green" onclick="add()">Health</span>
   <span class="btn-3d red" onclick="remove()">Damage</span>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: I know the code is pretty unorthodox but I've never done this before and was attempting to combine a couple of difference sources I had found. @Lain that worked perfectly, thanks for the help! How should I have done it to make it look more "normal"?

Answer (score 0):

Change the JS to:

```
let width=100;

function add() {
    let addHealth = document.getElementById('health')
    width +=1;

    if (addHealth) {
        addHealth.style.width = width + '%'; 
        addHealth.innerHTML = width * 1  + 'hp';
    }
}

function remove() {
    let damage = document.getElementById('health')
    width-=1;

    if(damage) {
        damage.style.width = width + '%'; 
        damage.innerHTML = width - 1  + 'hp';
    }
}
```

You had to make the variable width a global variable. And actually add and subtract from that variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
    let width = 100;

function add() {
let addHealth = document.getElementById('health')
    width =width+ 1 
    width=width>100?width=100:width
    if(addHealth){
        addHealth.style.width = width + '%'; 
        addHealth.innerHTML = width  + 'hp';
    }
}

function remove() {
    let damage = document.getElementById('health')
    width =width- 1
    width=width<0?width=0:width

    if(damage) {
        damage.style.width = width + '%'; 
        damage.innerHTML = width  + 'hp';
    }
}
```