# Dynamically updating a progress bar

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, progress-bar

How can I update a progress bar when certain points in my application have be passed please? For example I am trying to use something similar to this: (which is taken from [here](https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/twitter-bootstrap-tutorial/bootstrap-progress-bars.php))

```
<div class="progress">
    <div class="progress-bar" style="width: 10%">
        10%
    </div>
</div>
```

and then update the `width` by calling

```
$(".progress-bar").css("width", 30 + "%").text(30 + " %");
```

or

```
$(".progress-bar").css("width", 50 + "%").text(50 + " %");
```

at specific lines inside my other javascript functions called in my application. For example move the `width` by 20% when some operation on the data has finished etc... Apparently that is not the correct way since the bar doesnt move until the very end when everything is finished.

Any help greatly appreciated. In case it matters, everything happens on the client side,

Comment: check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62141203/13638059) it might help you.

Answer (score 0):

There are a variety of ways you could tackle this problem and I would recommend treating mine more as a jumping off point. But below is my recommendation for tackling this problem.

```js
$('body').on('click', '.progress', function(event) {
  var w_tar = $(this).find('.progress-bar'),
      w_cur = w_tar.data('width'),
      w_new = w_cur += 10;
 
  if (w_cur > 100) {
    w_new = 10;
  }
  
  w_tar
    .css('width', w_new + "%")
    .data('width', w_new)
    .text(w_new + "%");
});

$('.progress').trigger('click');
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="progress m-5">
  <div class="progress-bar" data-width="0"></div>
</div>
```

In the above snippet we replace your inline `style="width: 10%"` with a `data` attribute. This veers heavily into personal opinion but I find it a more reliable manner by which to update the element.  In my example I've started it off at '0' because I'm forcing the jQuery script to run once immediately.

The jQuery itself is fairly straightforward and functions with really only 3 variables:

- `w_tar` is the `.progress-bar` element
- `w_cur` grabs the current value of the `data-width` attribute
- `w_new` adds 10 to value of `w_cur`

From there we're really just doing what you already had in your original code. We're updating the inline style `w_tar.css(...)`, then updating the `data-width` so we can change it in the future `.data(...)` and finally outputting the text into `.progress-bar` with `.text(...)`.

There is also a quick check before we do all these updates to ensure your progress cannot exceed 100%.

Comment: Thanks, what I cant fugure out is how to update the progress bar width at load time. The value of the width might change inside the code, this is not reflected however in the progress bar because the contol is frozen